# How do I send signal to all processes in a cgroup?

Tags: linux, kill, cgroups, pkill

`kill $(< /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/<name>/tasks )` works, but looks clumsy, produces a warning if cgroup is empty and may hit command line length limit.

`pkill -F` does not accept cgroup tasks file as a valid pidfile.

There seems to be no dedicated tool like `cgkill`.

What should I use (apart from a fully fledged containers like LXC) to make forced cgroup termination more reliable and self-documenting? Ideally it should also do the { SIGTERM, then wait, then freeze, then SIGKILL, then thaw } routine.

Comment: Sounds like a fun open source task - add a new flag to `kill` or fix `pkill`...

Comment: `kill $(< /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/<name>/tasks ) ` has a race condition: new processes may be created in the cgroup between the time you enumerate PIDs and the time you kill them.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20599575 suggests that there's no reliable way to avoid the race condition (freezing the cgroup can freeze processes in an unkillable state) until cgroupv2.